# json, how to return specific value and not the object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

im new to this json and ajax thing, can some1 help me with this?

MY JS:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".testajax").submit(function(){


            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "controller.php",
              data: $(".testajax").serialize()
            })
              .done(function( msg ){
                $(".result").html("name:" + msg.name);

             });    

             return false;


        });
```

this is my Json

```
$return= array("name"=>$_POST);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($return);
```

my HTML

```
<form method="post" action="controller.php" class="testajax">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="">
    <button type="submit">SAVE</button>
</form>

<p class="result"></p>
```

what i want to do is when i input "Maria" in form and click save... the return result... should be "Maria". but, instead what i got is "name : Object"

Comment: What does your JSON look like?

Comment: @LeeTaylor The PHP is posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, you are inserting the whole POST array into the `name` element:

```
$return= array("name"=>$_POST);
```

So the JSON will look like this:

```
{
    "name": {
        "name": "john"
    }
}
```

Using that, you would have to change the JavaScript to use `msg.name.name`:

```
$(".result").html("name:" + msg.name.name);
```

You are seeing `Object` because `json_encode()` by default, converts associative arrays to objects (`$_POST` is an associative array). It would make more sense to put the name in the name element, not the whole POST array, like so:

```
$return= array("name"=>$_POST['name']);
```

Using that, your current JavaScript will work.

Comment: i know forbid to saying thanks.... but thank you for ur explanation about my problem....

Comment: Ah, nice catch. Did not see that one. +1